# PHP session not retained with AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I'm currently using the following JavaScript to send POST data to a website of mine:

`example1.com`:

```
function buttonFunction() {
    $.post("http://example2.com/core/file.php",{username:username, password:pword, coins:coins}, function(data) {
        // Stuff
    });
}
```

Then within `file.php` on `example2.com` I have the following:

```
<?php
namespace Penguin;

switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://example1.com': case 'https://example1.com':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    break;
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
error_reporting(0);

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['money_maker']) && $_SESSION['money_maker'] != "") {
    echo "Cannot run.";
} else {
    $_SESSION['money_maker'] = getmypid();
    echo $_SESSION['money_maker'];
    echo "Running.";
}

// REST OF THE PHP HERE

?>
```

As one can see, I set a session (if one has not already been set), and then if the session is already set, the script will echo "Cannot run."

However, the script never echos "Cannot run." even if I set the session on the previous AJAX run. In other words, the session is not being "saved." What's the issue? Any help?

Comment: Every time toy see "Running."?

Comment: @alexeypalamar Yep, every time I see the output "Running."

Comment: maybe `getmypid()` is returning `""`?

Comment: getmypid() can be closed for security reasons, can you check what return this function?

Comment: @andrew I have checked the output multiple times and it is returning a number.

Comment: @alexeypalamar It is returning a number.

Comment: @user3681788 alright im not sure what error reporting(0) is, may be try  `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` And... I don't think you should send headers before starting the session, that could be a problem

Comment: That looks like a typical problem with the session id. Have you checked a) if your browser has a cookie with the session id stored for `example2.com`, b) if it accepts a cookie that domain tries to set, and c) whether it gets send with the request that is made?

Comment: @CBroe It seems like the my browser does not have a cookie with the session id stored for `example2.com`. However, how can I check for b) and c)?

Comment: Use your browser’s developer tools to check – the net panel should tell you about received and send cookies in the request/response headers.